Make Looker Studio <> AWS Redshift use aggregate queries
I have a column called “total_revenue_earned” and another called “purchase_month”. If I try to make a bar chart summing revenue by month the query Looker Studio uses involves no aggregate functions. It is pulling the entirety of both columns and not aggregating at the db level. I think it is due to revenue being a dimension and not a metric but I don’t know how to switch it to be a metric.
